# What is the effect of not including the ["$scope"] argument in the 2nd argument of a controller?

Tags: angularjs

Based on what I have seen this:

```
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, Twilio, $http) {
```

works just as well as this:

```
app.controller('MainController', ["$scope", function ($scope, Twilio, $http) {
```

The Angular documentation does say to include the $scope dependency in the array, but the first method doesn't include an array at all, only the function, and still works.  Does it make any difference?

Comment: RTFM ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: Also, your second example won't inject `Twilio` or `$http` as you have not included them in the DI array. They will remain `undefined`. See http://plnkr.co/edit/SPPf8Iz2etHQXJQ8MYOG?p=preview

Comment: The code comes from some Twilio API documentation I found, `Twilio` and `$http` still works and I don't see any inject statements in any javascript files, unless it is implicit in app.config.  Will read more of the documentation though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about AngularJS dependency injection inconsistency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020390/confused-about-angularjs-dependency-injection-inconsistency)